# Custom logic on social Login

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

Is there any way to override the default social login providers and add some additonal functionality?

I would like to create an account directly as soon as the first login takes place.
Also I would like to know where the auth controller is implemented. Could not find it within https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server repository.
Where are these login/auth controllers are coming from?

Answer (score 1):

The authentication providers are in a module sitting in front of your service, so the authentication already happens before you get there.  You cannot add functionality to this module.

What you can do is call a custom API on login.  Normally, you would use the `client.loginAsync()` or `client.loginWithProvider()` methods (depending on the SDK in use).  Immediately after the login routine returns, call the `client.invokeApi()` (or the Async version) to call a custom API to do whatever you need to.